# Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available' XCODE 14 ERROR

Tags: flutter, dart

**Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available' XCODE 14 ERROR**

I have this error in Flutter project in XCode 14. One of the external packages were using:

@available(iOS 14.0, *)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
My current fix is:

> flutter_inappwebview: ^5.4.4+3

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be updating version in `Podfile platform :ios, '14.0'`, `pod update && Pod install`